# Read .TXT file and print response if value is true

Tags: python

I've got a TXT file that looks like this

```
[2019-04-03 13:59:15,034] | [DET ]: Detection 1 (start: 0.83, end: 1.57)
[2019-04-03 13:59:15,044] | [DET ]: Detection 2 (start: 1.74, end: 6.74)
[2019-04-03 13:59:15,062] | [DET ]: Detection 3 (start: 6.74, end:11.74)
[2019-04-03 13:59:15,071] | [DET ]: Detection 4 (start:11.74, end:15.97)
[2019-04-03 13:59:15,072] | [DET ]: Detection 5 (start:16.06, end:18.61)
[2019-04-03 13:59:15,081] | [DET ]: Detection 6 (start:18.82, end:20.60)
[2019-04-03 13:59:15,090] | [DET ]: Detection 7 (start:20.61, end:22.46)
[2019-04-03 13:59:15,094] | [DET ]: Detection 8 (start:22.48, end:23.58)
[2019-04-03 13:59:15,099] | [DET ]: Detection 9 (start:23.75, end:25.61)
[2019-04-03 13:59:15,101] | [DET ]: Detection 10 (start:25.64, end:26.60)
[2019-04-03 13:59:15,102] | [DET ]: Detection 11 (start:26.61, end:27.30)
[2019-04-03 13:59:15,289] | [DET ]: Detection 12 (start:147.91, end:149.09)
[2019-04-03 13:59:15,289] | [DET ]: Detection 13 (start:149.10, end:154.10)
[2019-04-03 13:59:15,289] | [DET ]: Detection 14 (start:154.10, end:156.03)
```

Is it possible for Python to read this and detect large gaps in values, see Detection 11 & 12 there is a large jump in numbers from 27.30 to 147.91, can a script read this and print a response e.g "Gap detected" along with the duration?

Thanks!

Comment: If your question is only "Is it possible?", then the answer is `Yes, absolutely. It's not even that hard`. Could you show us what have you tried so far? As a quick tip I recommend having a look at `readline()` in python which allows you to read a file line by line. While you're at a line, you could acces the desired data `147.91` and check it against the previous one `27.30`, if it exists. Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Irek, the problem being is that whilst I have tried readline the values differ in each txt file so I'm lost as it's not a specific value that I'm looking for each time.

Comment: I would try to fin `start:` and `end:` in the line, and extract those values, which is totally doable. So as long as those substrings are before your numeric values, you can extract them. Unless you're saying it's possible for the line to be like so: `[2019-04-03 13:59:15,289] | [DET ]: Detection 12 (begin:147.91, complete:149.09)` ?

Answer (score 0):

First I need to mock up your data to mimic a file handler.

```
s = """[2019-04-03 13:59:15,034] | [DET ]: Detection 1 (start: 0.83, end: 1.57)
# Omitted for brevity
[2019-04-03 13:59:15,102] | [DET ]: Detection 11 (start:26.61, end:27.30)
[2019-04-03 13:59:15,289] | [DET ]: Detection 12 (start:147.91, end:149.09)
[2019-04-03 13:59:15,289] | [DET ]: Detection 13 (start:149.10, end:154.10)
[2019-04-03 13:59:15,289] | [DET ]: Detection 14 (start:154.10, end:156.03)""".split("\n")
```

Next I need to extract the start and end values:

```
starts = []
ends = []
for line in s:
  # Extract start val
  start = line.split("start:")[1].strip().split(",")[0]
  # Cast as float
  start = float(start)
  starts.append(start)

  # Extract end val
  end = line.split("end:")[1].strip().split(")")[0]
  # Cast as float
  end = float(end)
  ends.append(end)
```

Note that `end = line.split("end:")[1].strip().split(")")[0]` with the important assumption that your strings are always properly formatted. And you see me cast to float so I can work with them as numbers.

Next I just compare the values against an arbitrary threshold (here, it's `20`):

```
for i in range(1,len(starts)):
  if starts[i]-ends[i-1] > 20:
    print("Gap detected: {}".format(s[i]))
  else:
    pass
```

Output:

```
Gap detected: [2019-04-03 13:59:15,289] | [DET ]: Detection 12 (start:147.91, end:149.09)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import re
import statistics as s
with open('name_of_the_file.txt','r') as f:
    z = f.readlines()
data = []
for i in z:
    temp = i.split('end')
    m =  re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", temp[1])
    if  m != None:
        data.append(float(m[0]))
    else:
        print(i)
for j in range(len(data)-1):
    cal = abs(data[j] - data[j+1])
    if ( cal > s.mean(data)):
        print(cal)
        print('Gap detected at '+str(j+2))
```

Output:

```
121.79
Gap detected at 12
```

Uses the mean of entire array as defining large step

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way:

```
import re

previous_end = -1

# Reading a file
with open('file.txt') as file:
    # Iterating over each line
    for line in file:
        # Spliting on ":"
        arr_lin = line.split(":")
        # Very bad way of accessing the number just after 'start' and 'end' 
        # However, if the file structure is always identical, so "(start: 0.83, end: 1.57)" this will do the job
        # Make sure we access the right index and convert it to float
        start = float(re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", arr_lin[-2])[0])
        end = float(re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", arr_lin[-1])[0])
        # Checking for your gap
        if (previous_end != -1):
            print("Gap detected {}".format(start-previous_end))
        previous_end = end
```

And the code presents us with this output:

[image: output]

`re.findall` extracts the float number from the string using regular expressions.

Hope that helps